# Debug a released app

Tags: android

I have integrated Facebook in my app. It works flawlessly in dev environment - on  both test device and app. But when I release this app and download from Market(now Play Store), it fails during login.

1) How do I check the logs of a released app?

2) Any hint what might be causing this problem? I am desperate enough that any help would be appreciated. *HINT* I'm logging in in UI thread. Is that a bad design? Should I spawn a separate thread?

Comment: `I'm logging in in UI thread. Is that a bad design? Should I spawn a separate thread?` -- anything that cannot be guaranteed to be instant should be done somewhere other than the UI thread. There are no exceptions to this.

Comment: @mah I agree. But I wonder how that gets caught only when I install from Market?

Comment: What are you logging, and - more important - **HOW** are you logging? Log.x()? To a webserver? Via mail?

Comment: @bos Using Log.x() to see it in my Logcat under eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was passing an invalid Facebook token. Now how did this still work on emulator is beyond me. Perhaps, Facebook SDK places less stringent checks when running on emulator?